# python-gnupg sign / verify a tar archive

Tags: python, gnupg, gpg-signature

I am using python-gpg to sign / encrypt / verify / decrypt a tar archive.

code snippet -

```
# import private key into gnupghome
_pvtKey = urllib2.urlopen(_certurl)
_pv_data = _pvtKey.read()
gpg.import_keys(_pv_data)
.....
stream = open("/tar/at/some/path/arh.tar", "rb")
    status = gpg.sign_file(stream, passphrase=_salt, detach=True, output="/output/sig/here.sig")
```

The code generated sig file just fine. However, if I try to verify the sig / tar using public keys, i receive following message -

```
gpg: armor header: Version: GnuPG v1
gpg: Signature made Tue 28 Aug 2018 07:48:28 PM UTC using RSA key ID 6B93AF63
gpg: using PGP trust model
gpg: BAD signature from "abc@def.com"
gpg: binary signature, digest algorithm SHA1
```

On contrary, if i try to generate sig file directly on linux and verify, it works fine.

I am loosing my mind on this, any pointers pls?

Comment: looks like some issues with sign generation process. If I manually generate the sig file using command line with pvt keys and try to verify from within python wrapper, it works fine. Makes me think some issues with sig generation process.

Comment: if i go for non-detach mode, then generated file gets verified just fine. how do i retrieve data from this file? am i supposed to provide both original tar as well as the generated file from sign process?

Comment: just in case anyone else comes across this error, i resolved it by compleltely moving away from the library and doing signing via Popen. Below references helped out - http://jeromebelleman.gitlab.io/posts/devops/pygpgstdin/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367140/python-popen-gpg-supply-passphrase-and-encryption-text-both-through-stdin-or-fi

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone else comes across this error, i resolved it by compleltely moving away from the library and doing signing via Popen. Below references helped out -

http://jeromebelleman.gitlab.io/posts/devops/pygpgstdin/

[Python/POpen/gpg: Supply passphrase and encryption text both through stdin or file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367140/python-popen-gpg-supply-passphrase-and-encryption-text-both-through-stdin-or-fi)